# pygame font list is [None]

Tags: fonts, pygame

I've reinstalled a system that is "embedded" with an interface using pygame.
Installing from repos or from source gives me [None] when running

```
pygame.font.get_fonts()
```

When using

```
font = pygame.font.SysFont("dejavusans",20)
```

I get horrible font rendering that doesn't even respect the size. I tried using the full font path ("/usr/share/[..]/DejaVuSans.ttf") and nothing changed.

Any clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is "Solved" by using pygame.font.Font with the complete path instead of using SysFont. I still don't know why the system font list is empty